# Why is rsync insisting there's a difference the second time I run it?

Tags: rsync, filenames

I'm resynchronizing my local Nextcloud directory after several months of it being offline. A while ago I lost a bunch of data on the server (don't ask) and ~3 different devices are way out of sync, so as a precautionary measure, I took a backup of the directory using `btrfs subvolume snapshot`.

Now I'd like to determine if there's anything in the backup that isn't in the partially-synchronized Nextcloud directory (which is at `~/ownCloud` because I used to be on ownCloud), i.e. if anything was deleted. To test this out I used this rsync command:

```
$ rsync -rvcn /var/backups/btrfs-snapshot-before-resynchronize-owncloud/home/alex/ownCloud/photos/Black\ and\ White\ Photography\ \(Winter\ \'14-15\) /home/alex/ownCloud/photos/Black\ and\ White\ Photography\ \(Winter\ \'14-15\)
```

The path in `/var/backups` is the snapshot version, and the path in `/home/alex` is the "live" version.

Unfortunately, this prints out (as far as I can tell) every file in the directory. Take `Black and White Photography (Winter '14-15)/19th.jpg` - this file is in both directories. It is the same by *every* measure - according to `stat`, it has the same size and inode number, and `md5sum` gives the exact same hash.

Why is `rsync` insisting that all these files are different even though they clearly aren't?

Comment: I would put '/' at the end of both directory arguments.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala UGHHHHHH. if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command does not have trailing '/' in the directory arguments (at least the first one), so the rsync tries to copy the first directory as a new directory in to the second directory.